# How to send images using SIM908 GPRS module using LPC2148

Tags: gsm, arm

I am working on a project in which I have to send an encrypted image via a GSM modem as GPRS or MMS. In this project the transmitter side consists of a PC, ARM LPC2148, and a GSM modem. The receiver also has the same set of components.

Now the question is:

Is it possible to send image from the transmitter to receiver via.

1. GPRS
2. MMS

If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: Possibly. You have TCP connectivity for example, if you receive a byte stream representing an image you can transfer those bytes via TCP and reconstruct the image from the byte stream on the other side. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097375/sending-images-over-sockets-in-c). The decontruction and reconstruction can be done on the PC.

Comment: TCP is possible over GPRS.